# $f(x_0)=0 \forall f \in X^*$ ($X^*$ is topological dual) then $x_0=0$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a normed vector space of infinite dimension (possibly) and $x_0 \in X$.

I would like to show that if $f(x_0)=0 \forall f \in X^*$ (the topological dual) then $x_0=0$.
I asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3070943/fx-0-0-forall-f-in-x-then-x-0-0?noredirect=1#comment6331689_3070943) but I forgot to mention that the functions were in the topological dual and not the algebraic dual, so I had an explanation for why this is true in the case of algebraic dual which was still very interesting.

The suggestion for when $f$ are in the topological dual was to use Hahn-Banach theorem. I have the version that says that a functional of $Y^*$ (where $Y$ is a subspace of $X$) can be extended to a functional of $X^*$ (again here we consider topological duals). But here I am not sure how this helps me. What should I consider for the subspace $Y$?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $f\in X^{*},$ then $x=y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3069076/prove-that-if-fx-fy-for-all-f-in-x-then-x-y)

Comment: This is in whatever book you learned the H-B theorem from. Assume $x_0\ne0$. Let $Y$ be the span of $x_0$. Take $\Lambda\in Y^*$ with $\Lambda(x_0)\ne0$, for example define $\Lambda(cx_0)=c$.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I am not familiar with those kind of reasoning yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_0$ is not the zero vector then consider the functional $f$ 
 which is defined on the space that $x_0$ spans as follows:
$f(a x_0)=a\|x_0\|$.
It follows from the Hahn-Banach theorem that there is a functional $F\in X^*$ with $F(x)=f(x)\ \forall x\in \text{span}(x_0)$ and of course $F(x_0)$ is not equal to $0$.